# Check typing for hybrid types

Tags: python, types, error-handling, instance, typing

Is there a function similar to `isinstance` that can identify if some data is of hybrid types, for example (suppose such a function is named `isinstance2`):

```
data = [1, 2, 3]
data2 = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

isinstance2(data, list[int])  # True
isinstance2(data2, list[int]) # False
isinstance2(data2, set[str])  # True
```

The use case is a class that checks types during instantiation:

```
class foo():

   def __init__(self, data):
       if isinstance2(data, list[str]):
           # do stuff
       else:
           raise TypeError
```

Comment: No. Python itself has no concept of homogeneously typed lists. `list[str]` is a type *hint*, not an actual type. `list[str]` behaves *somewhat* like a type, but only to the extent that it can be used like `list` itself. `list[str]([1,2,3])` is legal and returns an instance of `list` `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: You'd probably want to do something like `if data and isinstance(data[0], int):` to do that check manually.

Comment: @chepner typo, fixed.

Comment: If your most external type is always an Iterable (list, tuple, set) you could just do something like this: `all(isinstance(i, str) for i in data2)`

Comment: @HemersonTacon I like this, but it doesn't seem generic for use on any combination. ```all(isinstance(i, str) for i in data2)``` checks homogeneity for only strings, what if I wanted to infer the type ```str```, ```int```, ```bool```, whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generalise this kind of type-checking, you could maybe do something like the following:

```
from typing import Any, Sequence, Callable, Container

funcs_dict: dict[Any, Callable[[Any, Sequence[Any]], bool]] = {
    list: lambda container, args: all(
        isinstance(obj, args[0])
        for obj in container
        ),

    dict: lambda container, args: all(
        isinstance(key, args[0]) and isinstance(value, args[1])
        for key, value in container.items()
        ),

    tuple: lambda container, args: all(
        isinstance(tuple_elem, arg)
        for tuple_elem, arg in zip(container, args)
        )

    # etc for as many types as you want to include
    }


def runtime_generic_type_check(container: Container, annotation: Any) -> bool:
    origin: Any = annotation.__origin__
    args: Sequence[Any] = annotation.__args__

    return (
        isinstance(container, origin)
        and funcs_dict[origin](container, args)
        )
```

Examples:

```
>>> int_list = [1, 2]
>>> runtime_generic_type_check(int_list, list[int])
True
>>> from typing import List
>>> runtime_generic_type_check(int_list, List[int]
True
>>> runtime_generic_type_check(int_list, list[str]
False
>>> runtime_generic_type_check(int_list, tuple[int])
False
```

There are important caveats to this approach, however. This will essentially only work with very simple type hints — it won't work if you have a type hint like `tuple[str, ...]`, nor will it work for a nested container, like `dict[str, dict[str, int]]`. It also won't work for non-container type hints like `Callable[[<parameters>], <return-type>]`. You could alter the function to take account of these limitations, but the code quickly becomes much more complex. Finally, this works on my python 3.9 shell but not on my python 3.6 shell — `typing.List[str].__origin__` is `typing.List` in python 3.6, while it is `list` in python 3.9. I'm not sure when that change took place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this kind of run-type checking, you have to be explicit. Python itself has nothing built-in (though various libraries can and probably do exist to make this simpler):

```
class foo():

   def __init__(self, data):
       if isinstance(data, list) and all(isintance(x, str) for x in data):
           # do stuff
       else:
           raise TypeError
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it more general, so the type ```list``` can be inferred in ```isinstance(data, list)``` and ```str``` can be inferred in ```isinstance(x, str)```, as if it were ```isinstance(data, list[str])```?

Comment: The closest I can come up with would be `all(isinstance(x, type(data[0])) for x in data)` to check if every element of `x` is the *same* type (no matter what that one type is). There's no source of "ground truth" to infer a type of `list` or `str`.